# StackOverflow error with Graph Data structure

Tags: java, graph, stack-overflow

So I'm trying to write a method to see if a certain vertex is a part of a cycle, but I get this error

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
at graph.EdgeSet.neighbors(EdgeSet.java:42)
at graph.Graph.getNeighbors(Graph.java:127)
at graph.Graph.cycleHelper(Graph.java:164)
at graph.Graph.cycleHelper(Graph.java:171)
```

here's my methods

```
public boolean isInCycle(V vertex) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    if (!hasVertex(vertex)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Iterator<Vertex<V>> v = vertexMap.keySet().iterator();
    while (v.hasNext()) {
        Vertex<V> vert = v.next();
        vert.activated = false;
        vert.through = false;
    }
    return cycleHelper(vertex);
}

private boolean cycleHelper(V vertex) {
    Vertex<V> ve = vertexMap.get(new Vertex<V>(vertex)).vertex();
    ve.activated = true;
    Iterator<V> n = getNeighbors(vertex).iterator();
    while (n.hasNext()) {
        V vert = n.next();
        Vertex<V> curr = vertexMap.get(new Vertex<V>(vert)).vertex();
        if (curr.activated)
            return true;
        else {
            return cycleHelper(curr.vertex());

            }
    }

    return false;
}
```

could anybody point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: My first answer referred to an infinite recursion, but this was is not the case here: The `activated` flag already aims at preventing this.

There may be two main reason for a StackOverflowError: The first one is an infinite recursion (already ruled out here). The second one is that there are simply too many calls on the call stack. This can, in your example, happen when the algorithms has to traverse too many vertices before encountering the first cycle. ("Too many" here may mean "a few thousand", and depends on the maximum stack size, and the amount of memory that is required for each stack).

You may consider converting your method from a *recursive* into an *iterative* one. This may then simply be a breadth- or depth-first search.

I tried to implemement this here, but the structure (referring to the roles of `V`, `Vertex<V>`, the `vertexMap` etc.) is quite confusing, so I'm not entirely sure that this is correct:

```
public boolean isInCycle(V vertex) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if (!hasVertex(vertex))
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Iterator<Vertex<V>> v = vertexMap.keySet().iterator();
    while (v.hasNext())
    {
        Vertex<V> vert = v.next();
        vert.activated = false;
        vert.through = false;
    }

    Deque<V> queue = new LinkedList<V>();
    queue.add(vertex);
    vertexMap.get(new Vertex<V>(vertex)).vertex().activated = true;
    while (!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        V current = queue.removeFirst();
        Iterator<V> neighbors = getNeighbors(current).iterator();
        while (neighbors.hasNext())
        {
            V neighbor = neighbors.next();
            Vertex<V> n = vertexMap.get(new Vertex<V>(neighbor)).vertex();
            if (n.activated)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                queue.add(neighbor);
                n.activated = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have booleans activated

Comment: Don't I check if its been activated already? The vertex class has a boolean to check

Comment: @Dad Sorry, misinterpreted that. I'll edit the answer, but the new one will only be a guess (and if this is still wrong, I'll delete the answer)

Comment: when I run that, the code it doesnt end. The tests never end

Comment: @Dad Added a small edit in the code (the `else` case for the `if (n.activated)` clause)

Comment: sorry about late response, still same issue as before. When going to test it, it just never ends